# Python 3 Beginner - Python Docx String Manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

```
from docx import Document
import string
c_dic = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','y','z','m']
doc = Document('test3.docx')
firstSen = doc.paragraphs[0].text
indexLetters = 0
while indexLetters < len(c_dic):
    d_dic = c_dic[indexLetters]
    indexLetters += 1
    secondSen = firstSen.replace(d_dic,"")    
    print (secondSen)

#results:
#hello there
#hllo thr 
#hello there
#....
```

I am trying to remove sentences from the text3 document. The first sentence is "hello there". I am trying to run this script and erase the sentence. However, the script is only erasing pieces of the sentence and repeatedly giving me "hello there".

*edit
I plan to scale this to separate document with multiple foreign languages. So I'm trying to remove all the English passages from documents.

Comment: `sencondSen = firstSen.replace(d_dic, "")` it will replace the d_dic letter from firstSen and will store it in `secondSen` but you aren't changing the `fisrtSen` se `fisrtSen` will always remain same and loop will run 26 times because length of `c_dic` 26. Now you can modify your logic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the sentence why remove it letters. It is possible to remove the entire string in one shot.

If you just want to remove the first sentence then you  can just remove the first element of doc.paragraphs by slicing our the list like this:

```
first_sent_removed = doc.paragraphs[1:]
```

That assumes you want to remove first sentence always.

Suppose you would rather specify the string and search the paragraph for the sentence containing the text you want to remove. This will remove the bad sentence and return the other sentences in a list

bad_string = 'Hello there'

```
clean_para = [sent for sent in doc.paragraphs is bad_string not in sent]
```

Answer (score 0):

...
`doc.split()`
`remove = "words you want to remove".split()`

`for I in doc.paragraphs: 
    if I in string: 
        doc.paragraphs.remove(I)`

does this helps?